# How can you remove the white space between 2 elements while preserving the text alignment?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a menu bar the is centered on the screen.  To the left I have a  element as well as one to the right.  These have background images that tie the menu bar to the rest of the graphical layout.

The problem is that there are white spaces between the  tags.  Here is the CSS:

```
#menu_items {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 6px;
top: -9px;
height: 15px;
background-color: #75784D;
}

#swoop_left {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image: url('../imgs/menu_l.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 140px;
height: 21px;
font-size: 0px;
border: solid red 1px;
}

#swoop_right {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image: url('../imgs/menu_r.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 140px;
height: 21px;
border: solid red 1px;
}
```

The images themselves are 140px x 21px (w x h).

I can't float them because the menu won't center.  I can't use

```
font-size: 0px;
```

on the parent container because it won't display the menu items, and setting the menu-items  to

```
font-size: 1em;
```

afterwards doesn't fix the issue.

Anyone have a solution that will work in all browsers and doesn't rely upon JS?

NOTE: The borders of the two elements are for layout purposes only and won't be in the final code.

Comment: can you explain what tags are? "there are white spaces between the tags"

Comment: Could you please show the relevant markup?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are the items in the menu generated? In the div that contains the menu are you using an unordered list?

If you are then one possible solution would be to add the left and right images to the :first-child and :last-child elements of the list using css. You would no longer need the two extra div elements and so could just concentrate on the single menu container.

Answer (score 0):

There are four ways which i know & which you can use to remove the `whit space`.

1) as you said give `font-size:0;` to your parent DIV & define the `font-size:15px;` to your child divs.

2)You have to write your mark up in a `single line` like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>
<div>
```

Instead of this

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

3) Not that good solution but some time effective. Give margin-letf:-5px in your div. Like this:

```
div + div{margin-left:-5px}
```

4) At last you can use `float` instead of `inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

set background color to check your `div` width and height and you can use `margin-left:` with negative value to stand your `div` perfectly.